# How do I properly upload to PyPi such that extra packages are recognized

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am working on a python package, written in Python 3.11.  I am using a pyproject.toml file along with poetry to manage my dependencies.  The required and extra packages are included in my pyproject.toml file in the manner shown below.

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "package_name"
version = "0.1.2"
description = "A utilities module that contains classes and functions that simplify interfaces with files and databases."
authors = ["my_name <email-address>"]
readme = "README.rst"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
numpy = "^1.25.1"
xmltodict = "^0.13.0"
pandas = "^2.0.3"
pyyaml = "^6.0"
pyodbc = "^4.0.39"
mysql-connector-python = {version = "^8.1.0", extras = ["mysql"], optional = true}
pygresql = {version = "^5.2.4", extras = ["postgresql"], optional = true}
pdfplumber = "^0.10.2"
sphinx-rtd-theme = "^1.3.0"

[tool.poetry.extras]
postgresql = ["pygresql"]
mysql = ["mysql-connector-python"]
```

I am able to upload this package to the PyPi repository using the commands `poetry build` and `poetry publish` commands.  Once I use these commands the package is succesfully uploaded to PyPi and I can install the package using the following command.

```
pip install package_name
```

However, as you can see in the `.toml` file there are extra package dependencies such pygresql and mysql-connector-python that I should be able to install with one of the following commands.

```
pip install package_name[mysql]
pip install package_name[postgresql]
pip install package_name[mysql, postgresql]
```

However, when i type in any of the following commands, pip does not recognize the syntax. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and how I should fix this issue?

Comment: You could try to use quotes: `pip install 'package_name[mysql, postgresql]'`